# C++ Loan Calculator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program in C++ that takes a starting loan balance, the annual interest rate, and a monthly payment and prints a schedule that shows what the balance will be after every month until the loan is paid off or until 60 months have passed.

```
//Calculates a loan payment schedule

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

double startingBalance = 0.0;
double interestRate = 0.0;
double monthlyPayment = 0.0;
double monthlyBalance = 0.0;
double compountInterest = 0.0;
double balance = 0.0;
int month = 0;

cout << fixed << showpoint;
cout << setprecision(2);

cout << "Starting loan balance: " ;
cin >> startingBalance;  //User input starting loan balance
if (startingBalance <= 0){
    cout <<"\nPlease enter a positive number: " ;
    cin >> startingBalance;
}
cout << "\nAnnual interest rate: " ;
cin >> interestRate;  //User input interest rate
if ((interestRate <= 0) || (interestRate > 1)){
    cout <<"\nPlease enter an interest rate ranging from 0 to 1: " ;
    cin >> interestRate;
}
cout << "\nMonthly payment: " ;
cin >> monthlyPayment; //User input monthly payment
if (monthlyPayment <= 0){
    cout <<"\nPlease enter a positive number: " ;
    cin >> interestRate;
}

startingBalance = balance;

cout << "\nMonth \t Balance\n" << endl; //Outputs a schedule of payments

while ((balance > 0) || (month < 61))
{
    balance += (startingBalance * (interestRate/12));
    balance -= monthlyPayment;

    month = month++;

    cout << month << "\t" << balance << "\n";

}



    return 0;
}
```

I believe statements correct but I keep getting these as result

```
Starting loan balance: 10000.00

Annual interest rate: 0.0525

Monthly payment: 500.00

Month     Balance
1         -500.000
2         -1000.00
3         -1500.00
```

And so on until 61 months have elapsed.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Learn to **use a debugger** (`gdb` perhaps)

Comment: You never set the starting balance to the loan amount.

Answer (score 1):

```
startingBalance = balance;
```

that looks like it should be reversed

```
while ((balance > 0) || (month < 61))
```

your description suggests that && would be more appropriate